# ssh key for Bitbucket in Jenkins slave on Windows

Tags: jenkins, ssh, bitbucket

I have a Jenkins master on Linux and slave on Windows. Master jobs are able to clone the Git repository using `ssh` and we have config for this. But the same is not working from slave jobs. It is giving below error:

```
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."
```

I had configured Git tool location in slave node.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with slave node configuration.
Its explained here follow the link

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12353

Comment: thanks. But i didnt get any solution there. I need to know how to config ssh key for bitbucket from jenkins slave....

Comment: After adding the git tool location in slave node. getting error as "Host key verification failed".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The only difference was that my master was windows too.

It worked when I tried to manually git clone on the windows slave, but the error "stderr: Host key verification failed" occurred when I tried to trigger a build on the Jenkins master.

It turned out that, I started the Jenkins agent windows service as the "Local System Account". After I changed it to my own domain account, it worked.

So please:

1. Make sure it works if you manually git clone your remote repo on the window slave.
2. Check if your Jenkins slave is installed as a windows service.
3. If yes, change the "Log On" as your local account which is used for step 1, instead of the default "Local System Account".